# change order of array based on another array

Tags: javascript

Let say we have our array like this:

```
let myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

What if we want to modify the order of elements in `myArray` based on   `modifier` array so that, if `myArray` includes any element of `modifier` then we send that element to the end of the `myArray`

Like this:

```
let modifier =  ["B"] 
myArray = ["A", "C", "D", "B"] // B is sent to the end of myArray
```

And if we have this:

```
let modifier =  ["A", "C"]
myArray = ["B", "D", "A", "C"] // A and C are sent to the end of the array
```

I have tried looping and checking each array element against another but it went complicated...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple.

Step-1: Remove elements of modifier array from original array

```
 myArray = myArray.filter( (el) => !modifier.includes(el) );
```

Step-2: Push modifier array into original array

```
myArray = myArray.concat(modifier)
```

**Update**

As per demands in comments by seniors :) If use case is to move multiple data:

```js
var myArray = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var modifier = ["A", "B"];

// get static part
staticArray = myArray.filter( (el) => !modifier.includes(el) );

// get moving part
moveableArray = myArray.filter( (el) => modifier.includes(el) );

// merge both to get final array
myArray = staticArray.concat(moveableArray);

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: @JonasWilms what is your use case ? Please provide an example.

Comment: e.g. `array=AAABBBCDE, modifier=AB`

Comment: @georg : I have updated my answer with your use case as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could sort the array and move the items of `modifier` to the end of the array.

```js
function sort(array, lastValues) {
    var last = Object.fromEntries(lastValues.map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]));
    return array.sort((a, b) => (last[a] || - Infinity) - (last[b] || - Infinity));
}

var array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

console.log(...sort(array, ["B"]));
console.log(...sort(array, ["A", "C"]));
```

Comment: Fun fact: `Infinity-Infinity = NaN`. Since you already do `i+1`, why not just `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this to get desired result

```
    let myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
let modifier =  ["A", "C"];

for(let i=0;i<modifier.length;i++){
   if(myArray.includes(modifier[i])){
     myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(modifier[i]), modifier[i]);
     myArray.push(modifier[i]);
   }
}
console.log(myArray);
```